# "I would like to inform you", or "I would to inform you"?

Tags: word-choice, conditionals

"I would like to inform you", or "I would to inform you".

Which is better for a formal letter?

Comment: This is very GR. ‘Would’ cannot be followed by an infinitive with ‘to’; the second version is grammatically incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is correct, the second one is not.